# How to write DD-WRT C app?

Tags: c, dd-wrt

I want to write a small proxy as a user-level program for the DD-WRT environment.

The proxy will read/write between a USB HID device (Arduino) attached to the DD-WRT box and a specific web server. The USB device will use an AT-style code. The web server uses HTTP.

I'm new to the DD-WRT environment.

**Pointers to useful sample apps, GIT repos, blog posts, etc would be appreciated. Anything about getting started writing a DD-WRT app.**

Googling has not been successful.

Comment: BTW, have you considered using an Arduino ethernet shield to run the HTTP server on the Arduino itself, without touching the DD-WRT router?

Comment: @Tadeusz: I want wifi, not wired Ethernet. The Asus WL-520GU is much cheaper than a wireless shield, connects to the Arduino via USB and supplies pwr as well.

Answer (score 2):

More Googling and reading has led me to:

- Apparently, OpenWRT packages can be loaded onto DD-WRT systems. "Note that you can install any OpenWRT package, using ipkg." -- from a DD-WRT [page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorials)
- An [intro](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages) to writing an OpenWRT package.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Development

If you want to write a kernel module for DD-WRT, this seems like a good start.

Comment: Thanks. As I mention in the OP, I believe that a user-land app would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT has [packages](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_list_of_Optware_packages) for many useful things. Python and pyserial struck my attention.

It is [trivially easy](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html) to write a HTTP server in python. It is [equally easy](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to interface with a serial port in python.

Load kernel drivers for the USB serial emulator chip on your Arduino (mine has a FTDI chip). It will manifest itself as /dev/ttyUSB0 or something. Do everything else in python.

Comment: it takes a lot of space to install python on dd-wrt. so it will be possible for some (expensive) routers.